# How do I clean the value of the last TD in a table when I click on a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML piece of code:

```
<table class="table" id="table_data">
  <tbody>    
    <tr id="tr_2085">
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="2085" class="delete">
          Delete
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>United States of America</td>
      <td>US</td>
      <td>Post Warranty Service</td>
      <td>14.01</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And I am trying to clean (empty) the content of the last `td` when I click in a `.delete` link. This is what I am doing:

```
$('#table_data').on('click', '.delete', function(ev) {
  var item_id = $(this).data('id');

var that = $(this);
  that.closest('tr td:last').empty();
});
```

But isn't working since the value remains there. I have tried this too:

```
that.closest('tr td:last').text('');
that.closest('tr td:last').html('');
```

But isn't working either. I think the problem is on the selector I am using but I don't know what is the right one, any help? There is a Fiddle setup [here](https://jsfiddle.net/de2sgxkq/) for play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest('tr td:last')` needs to be `closest('tr').find('td:last')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table_data').on('click', '.delete', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  var item_id = $(this).data('id');

  $(this).parent().siblings('td').last().html('');
});
```